# HTML Form not submitting

Tags: html, forms, submit

Here is my simple code :

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body
{
    color:#F6F6F6;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid #E9E581;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:6px;
}
td
{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2B2B2B">
<div align="center">
<br><br><br>
<form action="dodajs.php" method="post">
    Ime: <br> <input type="text" name="ime"><br>
    Prezime: <br> <input type="text" name="prezime"><br>
    Adresa: <br> <input type="text" name="adresa"><br>
    Broj tel: <br> <input type="text" name="brojTel"><br>
    Broj indeksa: <br> <input type="text" name="indeks"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj novog">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My form is not submitting, aka not redirecting me to dodajs.php. I have more documents with more forms same as this one, and they all work, except this one... Am i doing something wrong ? Cant figure it out for the life of me

Comment: It works when I try it.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Yeah, I just used jsfiddle to test it, and it works there too... Insane stuff

Comment: There might be some JavaScript code that interferes with the submission. Start from your real problem page and omit parts until too see which code causes the problem. Or start from the code you posted (and remove the font stuff from it; it can hardly cause the problem) and add piecewise ingredients from your real page until the problem appears. Then, post a minimal document that actually reproduces the issue, unless you already saw what the cause is.

Comment: sorry, its work when i try it ... try to clear cash, or use private browsing ..